# create POOL on raydium using JS/TS

Tags: solana-program, dex, raydium

I want to create a market ID and pool on Raydium using JS/TS.

The transaction has been completed, but it does not appear on Solscan.

**edited:**

Create Market Transactions : [
'3zBEqtsNTcnio8wxZHmKXqgS4GNL7BXibzHmLVYKZZjTZfWxuDyya6xBWubyTXoEX7yys4QUvvRBeFQXorHjyHmi',
'3AXtbuaMrVZtWYgC5MVh9U3zAR9crrN4dFZK73shXBsncPTM65EUofjp9AiqMSX3UBdytVLQXnrZkAkPqpa7KRcm'
]

Market ID : PublicKey [PublicKey(HrRmmPNb4YzSk85z4y3PEmdrey3nYbYvkSzT5U9Fi5ue)] {
_bn: <BN: fa6475c5a17175376f64f74f83250182d376f5d22da0191dd36ee5d390b81785>
}

Here is the code for creating marketID

```
async function createMarket() {
    try {
        const createMarketInstruments = await MarketV2.makeCreateMarketInstructionSimple({
            connection,
            wallet: userWallet.publicKey,
            baseInfo: {
                mint: new PublicKey('6dPMkw1325CQZ5HAknCrr4PBRsJHL46kFAcwXmCVDhqv'),
                decimals: 6
            },
            quoteInfo: {
                mint: new PublicKey('GkpuJkzdV13qGaif9ZHFnfodiDHY6pz7jBhvnCaLJP2g'),
                decimals: 6
            },
            lotSize: 1, 
            tickSize: 0.01,
            dexProgramId: DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
            makeTxVersion: TxVersion.V0,
        })
        const txids = await buildAndSendTx(createMarketInstruments.innerTransactions, { skipPreflight: true })
    console.log('Create Market Transactions :', txids)
        return marketId
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("err: ", err)
        return err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's some links for your reference.

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/utilsCreateMarket.ts
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/ammCreatePool.ts

here's my working example

```
const {
    MarketV2,
    MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID,
    DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID
} = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk')

const {
    connection,
    makeTxVersion,
} = require('../config.js')
const { buildAndSendTx } = require('./util')

async function createMarket(input) {
    const RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID = process.env.NETWORK == 'mainnet' ? MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID : DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID

    // -------- step 1: make instructions --------
    const createMarketInstruments = await MarketV2.makeCreateMarketInstructionSimple({
        connection,
        wallet: input.wallet.publicKey,
        baseInfo: input.baseToken,
        quoteInfo: input.quoteToken,
        lotSize: input.lotSize, // default 1
        tickSize: input.tickSize, // default 0.01
        dexProgramId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
        makeTxVersion,
    })

    marketId = createMarketInstruments.address.marketId

    txids = await buildAndSendTx(createMarketInstruments.innerTransactions, { skipPreflight: true })
    console.log('Market Created')
    console.log('Create Market Transactions :', txids)
    console.log('Market Address :', marketId)

    return marketId
}

module.exports = {
    createMarket
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing, I recently used this but got the error, I'm using devnet and can't understand.
Error processing Instruction 5: custom program error: 0x1000694

Comment: you might be interacting with wrong program when creating market, kindly edit the post to share the tx with the issue, and the parameters you're passing to create the market.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet - it's working but the transaction can't show on Solscan. check the question I edit

Comment: I believe the issue might be related to the Devnet network not displaying the transaction on solscan.

Comment: I see, It seems there's some issue with devnet atm, it doesn't work on my side either. let us give it some time and try later.

Comment: Sure Thanks brother

Comment: how's it now?, It might work.

Comment: Yes marketID was created - Now this address make an issue while creating a pool  
   feeDestinationId: new PublicKey('7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5'), which address should i used here on devnet

Comment: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/blob/master/program/src/processor.rs

this should work for devnet:
3XMrhbv989VxAMi3DErLV9eJht1pHppW5LbKxe9fkEFR

Comment: Hi @cablespecific - what address should I used on const positionMint = new PublicKey('') adding th position on clmmaddPosition -> https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/clmmAddPosition.ts